# Site domain redirecting to the url of amazon web services bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, static-site

I have a static website which is currently being hosted in an AWS S3 bucket: `mysite.com`

I used GoDaddy to purchase the domain for `mysite.com` and I'm in the process of configuring this URL so that it points to my AWS S3 bucket. I believe I've configured the S3 bucket correctly as `mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` serves my static site.

However, I have a problem with my AWS Route 53. I set up a hosted zone with an alias, nameservers, and a start of authority.

My problem is that when I go to `mysite.com` in my browser, I am redirected to `mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. The site is correctly served from that address but I'm wondering why I'm being redirected to the AWS url.

Update -
This is the result of running `curl -IXGET mysite.com` in the terminal:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: FdG4UIjsT2AYvWlGZgtZFnUCoC5rlEpUoDWslfTiLxdtqfER5/VrK5pNaR0WgNQH+VtXvLM0dc0=
x-amz-request-id: D7F6E1CD65C36959
Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2016 17:46:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 22:10:36 GMT
ETag: "c4388dce1539caba654edf75cc674b7e"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 10364
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Are you using the root domain only? just mysite.com?

Comment: @RodrigoM We also have a www subdomain that redirects to mysite.com, but, yes, in my question I'm referring to the root domain.

Comment: Can you please post the the result of curl -IXGET http://example.com/, using your actual domain?

Comment: @RodrigoM just posted.

Comment: Hm its not redirecting there you are getting a 200.What does a curl -v to that site show?

Comment: What is your site domain?Can you give it tom me it will become easy to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can suggest is to double-check [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

I just tested the same setup here, and the domain does not redirect.

Under the S3 bucket properties, make sure the Redirect all requests to another host name is not set to an incorrect address.

Make sure the Route 53 record is using an IP alias record, as shown in the tutorial.